# ESLint: prefer-const doesn't throw an error even if variable is not reassigned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In my .eslintrc file, the value of `prefer-const` has been set to 2 and I do not override rules in the file.

All the rules seem to work fine. Even `prefer-const` rule seems to work fine. But, just for this particular code it's not throwing me any error. I am not re-assigning the value and I expect eslint to throw an error. I am using Atom as an editor.

```
  /**
   * Main render function
   */
  render: function () {
    // TODO: Show title based on the modal being opened i.e if New FAQ Modal
    // is opened show NEW FAQ else show the title of the FAQ.
    let title = "";

    return (
      <Modal title={title}
             className="faq-modal"
             loading={this.state.isModalLoading}
             hideHeader={this.state.isModalLoading}
             width="900px" />
    );
  }
```

### Editor, Plugins and Library

Atom: **1.12.9**

linter (atom): **1.11.8**

linter-eslint (atom): **8.1.2**

eslint: **2.7.0**

Comment: Interesting. remove the `title` attribute on `Modal` then it would throw an error. don't know why

Comment: When I paste your snippet in http://eslint.org/demo/ and check prefer-const, it does warn about title.

Comment: @Venugopal You're right. I get 2 errors.

1. 'title' is defined but never used
2. 'title' is never reassigned, use 'const' instead.

Weird. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

When variable `title` is used as an attribute of `Modal`, `eslint-plugin-react` adding a property called `eslintUsed`(which is being used, by `eslint`, to decide whether or not the variable is reassigned).

I don't completely know how this is being evaluated and all, but here is what I found out so far.

**acorn-jsx**

`acorn-jsx`module decides, while parsing JSX expressions, whether or not the variable is reassigned.

**file**: `acorn-jsx\inject.js`
[image]

Then `eslint-plugin-react` will set the `eslintUsed` prop on the variable.

**eslint-plugin-react:**

**file**: `eslint-plugin-react\lib\rules\jsx-uses-vars.js`
[image]

**file**: `eslint-plugin-react\lib\util\variable.js`
[image]

Finally, this prop(`eslintUsed`) is being used in `prefer-const` rule in `eslint` to(or not to) throw error/warning.

Hope this helps.